# How to detect multiple songs in the same audio file?

Tags: python, audio, fingerprinting

I am using python dejavu library.
It works fine and I was wondering if it is possible
to make it detect multiple songs in the same audio file.

One single mp3 file can contain one or more songs.

I need to recognize all the songs inside that mp3 file.
dejavu exists after the first match is found.

Any idea?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What kind of audio file? What is your criteria for saying something is a distinct song? (Like are you counting any space of a second with no sound as the space between songs, or how do you plan on determining when one starts and another ends?)

Comment: Are you talking about a sequential tracklist of songs, or a cocktail party of overlapping songs?

Comment: Can you take your long audio track and pass in small snippets over it's entire length, then take the dejavu output from these?

Comment: maybe trim them using sox tracks.wav snippet.wav trim [SECOND TO START] [SECONDS DURATION] and then pass these into dejavu.py

Comment: I'm flagging this question as unclear what you are asking, as there are not enough details included in the question to answer the question, until the OP edits it and includes the requested information.